# cohomological representations of GL(N)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, automorphic-forms, lie-algebra-cohomology

I am trying to understand cohomology of $G := GL(N)$. For this I need to understand representations of $G(\mathbb{R})$ with nontrivial $(\mathfrak{g},K_\infty)$-cohomology, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of $G(\mathbb{R})$ and $K_\infty$ is $O(N,\mathbb{R})$. Is there a classification of such representations?

Thank you.

Comment: In case you're interested, here are the numbers of representations of GL(n,R) with cohomology for n=2...10: [3,2,6,4,12,8,24,16,48] (computed by the Atlas of Lie groups and representations software).

Answer (score 5):

[Yes](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=762307). (That's assuming your definition of “representation” gives at least a $(\mathfrak g, K_\infty)$-module.)

Comment: The linked reference is to: *Vogan, David A., Jr.; Zuckerman, Gregg J.
Unitary representations with nonzero cohomology. 
Compositio Math. 53 (1984), no. 1, 51-90.*

Comment: Right; I believe the AMS site will show title and numdam link even without subscription. The review explains that they describe all Harish-Chandra modules (unitary or not) with nontrivial $(\mathfrak g, K_\infty)$-cohomology, and the paper adds that the OP's $GL(N)$ case is already in Speh ([1983](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/resolveppn/?PID=GDZPPN002099128)).

Comment: @Ziegler Thank you; the paper is useful.